# Sorting of an array in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

An array in .net is mutable and stored on the stack. Does sorting an array allocate new memory for the new sorted array, or use the same memory allocation of the initial array?

The following code gives me an output of 0 for both tasks. According to the textbook, the task1's value should fluctuate.

```
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
using static System.Console;
 
var nums = Range(-10000, 20001).Reverse().ToArray();
// => [10000, 9999, ... , -9999, -10000]
 
var task1 = () => WriteLine(nums.Sum());
var task2 = () => { Array.Sort(nums); WriteLine(nums.Sum()); };
 
Parallel.Invoke(task1, task2);
// prints: 5004 (or another unpredictable value)
//         0
```

Answer (score 5):

> An array in .net is mutable and stored on the stack.

Not that it matters for your question (since [the stack is an implementation detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one)), but, no, your array is not stored on the stack.

> Does sorting an array allocate new memory for the new sorted array, or use the same memory allocation of the initial array?

`Array.Sort` sorts the array in-place in a non-thread-safe way.

> The following code gives me an output of 0 for both tasks. According to the textbook, the task1's value should fluctuate.

Your PC is too fast to generate the race condition with your example code. You need to add more numbers (so that `Array.Sort` takes more time) and play around with delays. I was able to reproduce the expected behavior with the following code ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/89MLAt)):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
using static System.Console;
 
var nums = Range(-1000000, 2000001).Select(i => (long)i).Reverse().ToArray();
 
var task1 = () => { Thread.Sleep(30); WriteLine(nums.Sum()); };
var task2 = () => 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Sorting started");
    Array.Sort(nums); 
    Console.WriteLine("Sorting finished");
};

Parallel.Invoke(task1, task2);
```

prints:

```
Sorting started
1952 [or some other number, sometimes 0]
Sorting finished
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is clear and concise. Also the stack implementation is a nice addition.